# Can't upgrade the system, dist. update stuck

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade

I've just bought a Dell inspirion laptop , core i3 , 4gb ram , nvidia graphics (2gb vram) and it came with Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS which is nice cuz i need it for programming. But when i run distribution update from update manager it always gets stuck afterabout halfway, almost never at the same place(i had to return it to factory state a couple of times). I tried sudo apt-get -f install , tried sudo fuser /var/etc... and then 
 sudo apt-get -f install, it run the update but had some errors when installing kernels and couldn't load at all. Please help

P.S. I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux, i got the basics but I still dont get smoe things around here.

Comment: Please edit your question and insert list of errors you have

Comment: I killed compiz process which i thought stopped the update (it was the only running process) now i get a black screen and can't load the system

Comment: You shouldn't kill compiz. it's window manager for the X Window System. Switch to terminal number 1 (control-alt-F1) and run

DISPLAY=:0 unity --replace 
or

DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace

Comment: Ran unity --replace and got this: stop:unable to connect to system bus: failed to connect to socet /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: no such file or directory.               And compiz(core) loading plugin core, starting  and then fatal: couldnt open display

Comment: the correct command is `DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace` you don't include DISPLAY in ur command above

Comment: I did i just forgot 0 , but now it says Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keycompiz ... Couldnt open dispaly :0

Comment: Its not a problem for me to return it to 12 , it takes about half our and I dont have anything to lose , just tell me how to update it to 14 if possible, or should i download it to CD ?

Comment: just reboot and try update again if some error raise then better to do it from CD.

Comment: As I said i ran distribution update maybe 4-5 times and always the same thing , it stops and then i have to kill it, then the system wont load . I will try to dl it do cd and boot , tnx for ur time

Comment: Then it's better to try a CD installation

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Switch on your computer.

Press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select the line which starts with ---- `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with ---- `(recovery mode)`.

Your pc should display a menu with a number of options.

Select the line ---- `Drop to root shell prompt`.

In the terminal, run:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In the open file.

Delete the contents.

Paste the following:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-proposed universe multiverse restricted main
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, paste text. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Continue running:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Comment: tnx but I already installed it from CD ...